# Rails; How to select for a single database value with a scope

Tags: sql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, database, filter

I have a database called students with columns like so
[image]
In my rails model with a scope or function, I would like to select for the single age value based on the id. The id column is unique. So something like

```
scope :get_age, -> (id) { where(id: id).select(:age) }
```

However this does not seem to work. I would like for the returned value to just be the int 12. Using something like `pluck` ends up returning an array which I would like to avoid. How would I go about selecting for just the value of 12?

Comment: This is an abuse of scopes, you shouldn't do this, even if you can find a way to make it work. Scopes should return associations onto which additional scopes/`where` methods can be chained. What you want is `def self.get_age(id); find(id).age; end`. This will raise an exception if the record does not exist.

Answer (score 2):

you know that for one id there is just one row (or no rows) so using `where` or `pluck` is not ideal, we want something it returns one row or nothing (`find`, `find_by` etc)

```
def self.get_age(id)
  find_by(id: id)&.age
end

some_id = 10
User.get_age(some_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

> Scoping allows you to specify commonly-used queries which can be referenced as method calls on the association objects or models. With these scopes, you can use every method previously covered such as where, joins and includes. All scope bodies should return an ActiveRecord::Relation or nil to allow for further methods (such as other scopes) to be called on it.

Reference: https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#scopes

That's why is not working as you expected.

I think the best alternative would be to do as Ursus suggested. Create a method, a query object, etc.

Answer (score 0):

You basically want to read an attribute(`age`) of your model object. For that, you don't need to write any specific method or scope.
Here is what you can do in the place where you have the `id` and you want to fetch the age for that record:

```
object = YourClass.find(id)
object.age
```